# How to get a time estimation of an O(n) function to modern multi-core CPU time?

Tags: big-o-notation

How to get an estimation of an O(n) function to modern multi-core CPU time? For instance, how can I find the time it takes to run an algorithm in a 4-core/8-core CPU when I know its O(n) ? I searched on google I find nothing about my question...

Comment: You could run the function. If you just know that the function running time is in $O(n)$ then you cannot say much. $1$ and $10^{10^{10}} n$ are both in $O(n)$.

Comment: Ok, for O(2^48) and O(2^32) ?

Comment: $O(2^{48})$ and $O(2^{32})$ are both synonyms of $O(1)$. Your function running time is at most some constant. AS for how big this is, that depend son the hidden constants (and technically non-constant terms) hidden by the the big-oh notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is not trivial.

First of all, let's talk about asymptotical analysis: if you have a (small) constant number of cores $k$, e.g. $k=8$ or $k=16$, even if your application has an ideal speedup of $k$, the asymptotic execution time is still $O(\frac{n}{k})=O(n)$. Thus, asymptotical analysis doesn't help us in this scenario.

Now, we have to talk about parallelizzability. Having more cores does not always mean having more speed. Consider the following problem:

You have a black-box function $f$ and you have a program which takes in input a value $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and an integer $n\geq 0$ and gives as output $f^n(x)$, where $f^n$ indicates the composition of $f$ $n$ times.

Since $f$ is a black-box function, in order to obtain $f^n(x)$ the only thing you can do is to apply $f$ iteratively, until you get $f^n(x)$. This program is clearly not parallelizable, because even if you have more than one core, the only thing you can do is iteratively apply $f$ to the new value.

If instead, you have some operation like summing two vectors of length $k$, you can make each core sum one component, obtaining so the maximum level of parallelization.

Between these two extreme examples, there is a world. You often can parallelize only a portion of your program.

Then, out of the ideal world, there is something called *overhead*, which is the cost of parallelizing. The parallelization needs to be managed by the programming language, for instance you need to create threads and assign the work to each thread and this has a cost.

If you try to parallelize the first program (the unparallelizable one) with all your $k$ cores, the only result you will obtain is a program which is slower than the sequential one, because you try to manage a lot of threads but then you end up using only one of them.

In conclusion, parallelization is not a trivial task and it has to be evaluated in specific use-cases with the opportune metrics instead of using asymptotic time complexity analysis alone (e.g. speedup, efficiency, scalability, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Big-O tells you an upper limit for the execution time up to a constant factor. And the difference in execution time between a Zuse Z3 and today’s leader in the top 500 supercomputer list is also just a constant factor. So Big-O tells you nothing about the execution time.

If instead of Big-O you examine a problem much more carefully then you may be able to say “this problem takes roughly 123 n^2 fast instructions to find a solution, it is not limited by memory access, my processor can do about 2.5 instructions per cycle on average, at 3 billion cycles per second, and eight cores which need to perform 10% more instructions than a single core”, then you could estimate that the total time to run this for some n might be 123 n^2 * 1.1 / 60 billion seconds of 2.25 n^2 nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that the theoretical complexity of an algorithm is $O(n)$ tells you very little. Because

- it is only an upper bound, there is no guarantee that it is tight;
- the conversion to real-world times depends on the "hidden constant", which you don't know,
- more importantly, the usual models of computation rest on the assumption that memory accesses are done in constant time. This is plain wrong ! In fact, memory accesses take time that highly depends on $n$, on the pattern of accesses and other factors. The time is not even deterministic ! Running the same program twice on the same data, you may observe large deviations.

---

Regarding the behavior when you increase the number of cores, the answer is simple: the time does not depend on it because unless you explicitly parallelize it, your program will keep running on a single core. In fact it can run slower in case of switches between the cores, or contention caused by other tasks.

You might say that the time can reduce because other active tasks may run on other cores, but when you look at typical machine activity, you will notice that most of the cores are just idle.

---

Example activity:

[image]

---

If you are lucky, your algorithm might be parallelizable, but that usually comes at the cost of a (possibly complicated) rewrite. As synchronization and task decomposition add overhead, you will get less than speedup $n$ for $n$ threads.

If you are unlucky, no parallelization will be possible, or parallelization will result in a program that is slower than the single-threaded version.